# Linux: using a virtual network inside a bridge

Tags: linux, networking, bridge

**Premise:**

I am using a raspberry pi3 as AP.
I have added an USB to ethernet adapter and this is the configuration I have:

- built in eth port as eth0 (WAN)
- built in wifi interface as wlan0 (LAN, wireless)
- usb to ethernet adapter as eth1 (LAN, wired)

I have bridged successfully wlan0 and eth1 into a bridge, br0.

Then I have setup a nat to allow the devices on br0 to connect to the internet.  All of this works.

**Problem:**

Now I would like to split the wired LAN, so that there is a virtual network (eth1:0) for trusted devices and another virtual network for less trusted devices (eth1:1).

The idea would be to add to br0 only eth1:0.
This seems to work, but when I list the bridges, br0 seems to use directly eth1, instead of the virtual interface eth1:0.

In fact, if I try to create another bridge (br1) and add the other virtual network (eth1:1), I get an error saying that the interface is already in a bridge.

So it seems that a virtual interface cannot be added to a bridge, only its parent.

Is this true?
Is there some other way to do it?

This is the test script I am using:

```
function configure_firewall() {
    echo  CONFIGURE FIREWALL START
    ####################### FORWARDING #####################
    # Enable IP forwarding
    echo 1 > /proc/sys/net/ipv4/ip_forward

    # Allow forwarding of traffic LAN -> WAN
    iptables -A FORWARD -i ${BRIDGE} -o ${WAN} -j ACCEPT

    # Allow traffic WAN -> LAN but only as reply to communication initiated from the LAN
    iptables -A FORWARD -i ${WAN} -o ${BRIDGE} -m state --state RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT

    # Drop anything else
    iptables -A FORWARD -j DROP

    ####################### MASQUERADING ########################

    # Do the nat
    iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -o ${WAN} -j MASQUERADE

    ###################### INPUT #############################
    # Allow local connections
    iptables -A INPUT -i lo -j ACCEPT

    iptables -A INPUT -i ${BRIDGE} -j ACCEPT
    iptables -A INPUT -p tcp --dport 22 -i ${WAN} -j ACCEPT
    iptables -A INPUT -i ${WAN} -m state --state RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
    iptables -A INPUT -j DROP

    ###################### OUTPUT #############################
    iptables -A OUTPUT -j ACCEPT
    echo  CONFIGURE FIREWALL END
}

function teardown_bridge() {
    echo TEARDOWN BRIDGE START
    ifconfig ${BRIDGE} down
    brctl delif ${BRIDGE} ${LAN}:0
    brctl delif ${BRIDGE} ${WIFI}
    brctl delbr ${BRIDGE}
    echo TEARDOWN BRIDGE END
}

function configure_bridge() {
    echo CONFIGURE BRIDGE START
    brctl addbr ${BRIDGE}
    brctl addif ${BRIDGE} ${LAN}:0
    brctl addif ${BRIDGE} ${WIFI}
    ifconfig ${BRIDGE} up 192.168.10.1 netmask 255.255.255.0 broadcast 192.168.10.0
    echo CONFIGURE BRIDGE END
}

function configure_interfaces() {
    echo CONFIGURE INTERFACES START
    ifconfig ${LAN} up 0.0.0.1
    ifconfig ${LAN}:0 up 0.0.0.2
    ifconfig ${LAN}:1 up 0.0.0.3
    echo CONFIGURE INTERFACES END
}

function teardown_interfaces() {
    echo TEARDOWN INTERFACES START
    ifdown ${LAN}:1
    ifdown ${LAN}:0
    ifdown ${LAN}
    echo TEARDOWN INTERFACES END
}

function delayed_reset() {
    for i in `seq 15 -1 0`; do
        sleep 1
        echo ${i}
    done
    sync
    reboot
    exit
}

#test_network

#if [ $? -ne 0 ] ; then
    teardown_firewall
    teardown_bridge
    teardown_interfaces
    configure_interfaces
    configure_bridge
    configure_firewall
    #delayed_reset
#fi
```

After running the script, if I run `ifconfig`, it looks like the virtual networks exist:

```
eth1      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 00:13:3b:62:11:f6  
          inet addr:0.0.0.1  Bcast:255.255.255.255  Mask:0.0.0.0
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:30712 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:19110 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:5261152 (5.0 MiB)  TX bytes:5355909 (5.1 MiB)

eth1:0    Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 00:13:3b:62:11:f6  
          inet addr:0.0.0.2  Bcast:255.255.255.255  Mask:0.0.0.0
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1

eth1:1    Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 00:13:3b:62:11:f6  
          inet addr:0.0.0.3  Bcast:255.255.255.255  Mask:0.0.0.0
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
```

But the entire `eth1` appears to be in `br0`:

```
root@raspberrypi:/home/pi# brctl show
bridge name     bridge id               STP enabled     interfaces
br0             8000.00133b6211f6       no              eth1
                                                        wlan0
```

And this seems to confirm it:

```
root@raspberrypi:/home/pi# brctl addbr br1
root@raspberrypi:/home/pi# brctl addif br1 eth1:1
device eth1:1 is already a member of a bridge; can't enslave it to bridge br1.
```

**Note:**
I did look at [Create and bridge virtual network interfaces in Linux](https://serverfault.com/questions/365409/create-and-bridge-virtual-network-interfaces-in-linux?rq=1) but it seems to be obsolete, as it refers to iproute2.

Comment: Since you show a lot of `iptables` configuration and no `ebtables`, yet you're using a bridge, you should probably start reading about it now.

Comment: JuliePelletier thank you. I'm doing this as hobby project, never had much of a chance to work on routing and somehow ebtables has maanged to go under my radar in all these years. Is http://ebtables.netfilter.org/br_fw_ia/br_fw_ia.html a good starting point or would you recommend to start elsewhere?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't create `br0` and `br1` bridges on one interface eth1, because `eth1:0` and `eth1:1` is the same interface eth1 with two different ip addresses.
You can create vlan If your wired network and switch allow it. If you create two vlans `eth1.10` and `eth1.20` you will have two different interfaces, witch can be used for bridges `br0` and `br1`.

Comment: Thank you, now I see my error. I got confused and assumed multiple addresses would qualify as virtual network, instead I really need a new interface.

Comment: For the record, this is what got me confused: https://linuxconfig.org/configuring-virtual-network-interfaces-in-linux
If I now understood correctly, the article is misusing the word "virtual", to represent what is actually a multiple-address configuration, as opposite to a full vlan deployment.

Comment: Yes. This article at linuxconfig.org is wrong. Read about KVM and linux network on Redhat documentation site.